# Center div in div margin auto doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Hi I have the following code:
**CSS**

```
.center{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav{
    background: #606060;
    width: 90%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="center">
             <div class="nav">
                <p>Ahoj</p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also tried `.center` without `width:` I searched throught themes here but I didn't find a solution. `.nav` div still stays on the left.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to add `margin: 0 auto;` to `.nav` and then set `text-align: center` ?

Comment: @Krusader Thank you! That works!

Comment: I've added an answer below so if it helped you please consider to check it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Give `margin:0 auto` to `.nav` class not to `.center` class.

```css
.center{
  width: 100%;   
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav{
  background: #606060;
  width: 90%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="center">
             <div class="nav">
                <p>Ahoj</p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define margin: 0 auto; when width is 100%. It is required if you want to position division of fixed width to the center of parent div.

```css
.center{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav{
    background: #606060;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
     <div class="nav">
        <p>Ahoj</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your `.nav` class

```
.nav {
 .
 .
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

block level elements can't be centerd because its always fit in `100%` width of its container so I suggested to use `inline-block` instead.

```css
.center{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
}

.nav{
    background: #606060;
    width: 90%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
        <div class="center">
             <div class="nav">
                <p>Ahoj</p>
             </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.nav {
background: #606060;
width: 90%;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

Comment: where is the explanation, just dumping code is not a good answer

Comment: *perfectly fine?* can you describe the solution? explain why this CSS code should work. I can see only CSS code (no snippet, not well formed). I *(I'm not the downvoter)*

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think a whole tutorial was needed for such a question. Since when stackoverflow became a tutorialzine ?

Comment: read the help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.